# Xamarin Forms, when I release my app on appstore (Testflight) the labels fontsize is different on different iPhone 6s devices

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am very confused why this is happening. On some iPhone 6 devices the fontsize is bigger and on others it looks normal (like it does on the simulator). Any idea why this is? I googled it a bit and saw a post about the launchscreen maybe having a connection with this?

I use a xib right now as launchscreen, could that be the issue or is there something else?

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few reasons. If you allow the `FontSize` of a `Label` to be `Default` then a user could go into their device's Accessibility options and increase the font size across the entire device.

You may want to try setting a specific `FontSize` to see if that makes a difference, using either a number or using the `Device.GetNamedSize()`.

But having said that, it may be better to allow the user to set a larger size if they have a hard time reading smaller text. So you may want to change your UI to allow for that kind of flexibility in size, if that is possible.